# Generic XML parser in Silverlight 3.0

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Hi I am developing an application in Silverlight 3.0, I want to make a generic parser of XML in it, as on every call to webservice I am receiving a different XML, I want to make it generic so that I receive an XML in native datastructure of C#? Please help me out?
like I am getting XML like this one time

```
<test>
 <node1></node1>
 <node2></node2>
</test>
```

and other time

```
<mytest>
 <application name="XYZ">My Application</application>
 <application name="ABC">My Application</application>
</mytest>
```

I want the generic parser, e.g. it makes some tree structure of whole XML

Comment: Simple solution: why can't you just receive a string client side and read it in to an XmlTextReader or a XmlDocument?

Comment: how I can do it using XMLReader? I have found some examples but all are for some specific type of XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution [Generic XML parser](http://forum.codeproblem.com/silverlight/generic-xml-parser-in-silverlight-3-0) works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .NET [xml serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90c86ass(v=VS.71).aspx).

Given the xml that looks like this

```
<TestObject>
    <FirstProperty>SomeValue</FirstProperty>
    <SecondProperty>17</SecondProperty>
</TestObject>
```

C# object

```
[Serializable]
public class TestObject
{
    public string FirstProperty { get; set; }
    public int SecondProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code to convert the xml to the object

```
string xml = @"<TestObject>
                    <FirstProperty>SomeValue</FirstProperty>
                    <SecondProperty>17</SecondProperty>
                </TestObject>";

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestObject));

using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    using (XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(reader))
    {
        TestObject obj = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader) as TestObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to prevent misunderstandings: You do not need the Serialize attribute to use the XmlSerializer. Has no effect for this kind of serialization.

Comment: but for this type of parser I need to make Serializeable object for each XML, e.g if I had 100 type of XMLs, then I need 100 objects... This is not feasible for me. I want just to store them in a Generic structure, like List or Dictionary.